# How do I create ENTITY references in the DOCTYPE using perl/LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, entity, dtd, xml-libxml

I'm trying to create the following DTD containing entity declarations:

```
<!DOCTYPE LinkSet PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD LinkOut 1.0//EN" "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/linkout/doc/LinkOut.dtd" 
[ <!ENTITY icon.url "https://example.com/icon.png"> 
<!ENTITY base.url "https://example.com/content/" > ]>
```

I can successfully create the DOCTYPE *without* the entity references:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0','UTF-8');
my $dtd = $doc->createInternalSubset( "LinkSet", "-//NLM//DTD LinkOut 1.0//EN", "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/linkout/doc/LinkOut.dtd" );

my $ls = $doc->createElement( "LinkSet" );
$doc->setDocumentElement($ls);

print $doc->toString;
exit;
```

Results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE LinkSet PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD LinkOut 1.0//EN" "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/linkout/doc/LinkOut.dtd">
<LinkSet/>
```

The [XML::LibXML documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod#createEntityReference) shows how to add an entity reference to a document, but not how to declare an entity in the DOCTYPE.

A [similar (but PHP-based) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876393/adding-entity-nbsp-160-to-the-doctype-using-php-dom) points to creating the ENTITY references as a string and parsing that.
Is this the best approach in Perl too?

Comment: The entity declarations are nodes of type `XML_ENTITY_DECL` that exist as children of the DTD node. `$node->addChild` doesn't support adding nodes of type `XML_ENTITY_DECL`, so you wouldn't be able to add one even if you could create it. Therefore, the parse-to-generate approach solution that's been posted is probably the only way to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`XML::LibXML::Document`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod)
says this

> [The Document Class] inherits all functions from `XML::LibXML::Node` as specified in the DOM
>   specification. This enables access to the nodes besides the root element
>   on document level - a "DTD" for example. The support for these nodes is
>   limited at the moment.

It also makes it clear later on that the source of these limitations is `libxml2` itself, not the Perl module. This makes sense, as the DTD has a completely different syntax from XML (or even an XML Processing Instruction) even though it may look superficially similar.

The only way appears to be to parse a basic document with the required DTD and work with that

Like so

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<__END_XML__);
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE LinkSet PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD LinkOut 1.0//EN" "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/linkout/doc/LinkOut.dtd" 
[
  <!ENTITY icon.url "https://example.com/icon.png"> 
  <!ENTITY base.url "https://example.com/content/">
]>

<LinkSet/>
__END_XML__

print $doc;
```

#### output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE LinkSet PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD LinkOut 1.0//EN" "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/linkout/doc/LinkOut.dtd" [
<!ENTITY icon.url "https://example.com/icon.png">
<!ENTITY base.url "https://example.com/content/">
]>
<LinkSet/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I had read that in the documentation, but thought I might have been missing something e.g. in `XML::LibXML::Dtd`.